# Android: Dealing with multiple device specific libraries

Tags: android, jar, libraries, device

I have an Android project that doesn't need to change much, 95% is not device specific. However some of the device I am developing for require specific libraries to be included along with minor changes to the manifest file. There is no overlap between these libraries so they are unique to each device.

Individual projects for each would be a pain to manage since I'd have to replicate fixes in the non-device specific areas multiple times.

How would you suggest dealing with this?